# Problems installing elementary tweaks in Juno

Tags: release-juno, apt, ppa, thirdpartyapps

Following these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

I get this output, indicating an error:

```
guillermo@guillermo-Elementary:/media/Aplicaciones/LibreOffice_6.0.6.2_Linux_x86-64_deb$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 107, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 128, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 623, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for elementary/juno
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install `software-properties-common`?

Answer (score 0):

run these commands and paste them

```
$ egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
```

this is my lsb-release file

```
DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=juno
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 5.0 Juno"
```

if yours is different, write it like mine

```
$ sudo nano /etc/lsb-release
```

(you can change nano and use another editor to do the job)

Comment: try run these commands in your home folder, not libreoffice.